# Regex replacement issue: using group

Tags: regex, ultraedit

I need to replace hundreds of `if (ereg("avion","$keyw"))` by `if (preg_match("@avion@","$keyw")) {`

I tried this:

1st : `ereg\("(.*)"`

2nd : `preg_match\("@$1@"`

But it replaces the first group by '$1'... Any idea please?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Jerry appears to be php

Comment: php, but here I try to use ultraedit editor which permit regex expressions... Or use sed in bash perhaps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working on the UltraEdit version I have:

[image]

I'm just not sure why you have `@` in your replace.

You can pick "Current file" for all instead of the "Selected Text" I used for the comparison.

Another thing to note, it might be safer to use:

```
ereg\("(.*?)",
```

Replace:

```
preg_match("@$1@",
```

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right, I just choose "UNIX" instead of "Pearl"... Thanks

Comment: Missing delimiters (I choose @, but it can be /), and it only put the 1st delimiter not the second!

Comment: Work with `ereg\("(.*)",` and `preg_match\("/$1/",`

Comment: @user2670167 Ooh, you mean putting the delimiters in the preg_match, sorry you're right there :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` you can try this way:

```
sed -i".bak" 's/(ereg("\([a-z]*\)","\$keyw"))/\(preg_match\("@\1@","$keyw"\)\)/' filename
```

EDIT: Updated to match any word, not only 'avion'

Comment: Thx but I need a global regex, not just for "avion", I have hundreds of expressions like this...

Comment: Ok, filename can be *.php?

Comment: Ok, it works but I have some lines with `ereg("internet, internets"` which are not replaced...